# Monoid structures induced on hom objects

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

If $a$ is a set and $b$ is some algebraic structure, then the set of functions $a\to b$ also has the obvious algebraic structure. **Is there a popular categorification of this?**

More abstractly, let $V$ be a monoidal cetegory whose unity object is denoted by $i$. Let $a$ be a comonoid object and let $b$ be a monoid object in $V$. Then we can define a morphism $\bot:a\to b$ by
\begin{equation}
    \bot=\left(a\xrightarrow\top i\xrightarrow\bot b\right)\text.
\end{equation}
Also, for morphisms $f,g:a\to b$, we can define a morphism $f\triangledown g:a\to b$ by
\begin{equation}
    f\triangledown g=\left(a\xrightarrow\triangle a\otimes a\xrightarrow{f\otimes g}b\otimes b\xrightarrow\triangledown b\right)\text.
\end{equation}
If we assume further that $V$ is closed, this defines a monoidal structure on $[a,b]$ (I did not check it). What is the most popular or general framework of these concepts?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "categorification". It seems to me more like you mean "category-theoretic generalisation" or "in category-theoretic language". But "categorification" actually refers to something more specific, and different.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, then you are right. I did not know the precise meaning of categorification.